# using existing tcl c procedures in tcl script

Tags: command, tcl, procedures

How to use Tcl_ParseCommand or list of Tcl C procedures already available under "http://tmml.sourceforge.net/doc/tcl/". Do i need to write wrapper c procedure and init procedure for each of these command?

-Prasath

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. To use the Tcl C-API you either build a Tcl extension package or embed a Tcl interpreter into your own C program (have a look at the sources for the tclsh shell).

Comment: My purpose is to use the tcl c procedures in my tcl script. could you let me me know how to create an Tcl extension package for these existing c procedure available in Tcl library. i'm not looking to create my own command in c.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to access the parser commands Tcl_ParseCommand etc. might be the tclparser extension (e.g. the (orphaned) tclparser package in Debian/Ubuntu or build yourself from the sources http://wiki.tcl.tk/1660).

If you need to handle other Tcl C-library commands as well, you should have a look at how to write a Tcl extension in general. A lot of examples and advice for that can be found at: http://wiki.tcl.tk/1191

Comment: Thats great. Thanks for the suggestion. Since Tcl c libraries like Tcl_ParseCommand etc are inbuilt, i thought there must a gereric way already available to get this working in tcl scripts without a need to write an extenstion for each c api. It seems i've to extend these c libraries as if i do for new c procedures. (am i correct?).

Comment: Most of the Tcl c api just does the same as simple Tcl commands, so in a way you have direct access to most of them, but there are some parts of the c api that are less useful or needed in the script layer. For example Tcl_Eval is just the same as eval or source or namespace eval or interp eval or one of the other ways to eval a script. In fact there are very few functions not available in a normal script, mostly initialization, memory allocation and other utilities, or deep internals like registering new event sources to the notifier. All the rest is just a Tcl command in disguise.

Comment: hmm. ok. the issue is writing c extension for each tcl c libraries is cumbersome for me as i've little knowledge in c. Also its difficult for me to understand how to passs required arguments to the tcl c api from the wrappers and then convert the return values of these c api's back to tcl script.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do need to write a wrapper C-implemented command to use those. However, there are a number of neat tools to make that easier. In particular, [critcl](http://equi4.com/starkit/critcl.html) is interesting choice, which you might use like this (very noddy example):

```
package require critcl
critcl::cproc foo {Tcl_Interp* interp Tcl_Obj* argObj} ok {
    int nObjs;
    Tcl_Obj **objs;

    if (Tcl_ListObjGetElements(interp, argObj, &nObjs, &objs) != TCL_OK)
        return TCL_ERROR;
    if (nObjs != 2) {
        Tcl_AppendResult(interp, "need list of length 2", NULL);
        return TCL_ERROR;
    }
    Tcl_SetObjResult(interp, Tcl_NewBooleanObj(
            !strcmp(Tcl_GetString(objs[0]), Tcl_GetString(objs[1]))));
    return TCL_OK;
}
puts [foo {a a}]
```

The useful documentation is [on the Tcler's Wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/11814).

Note that for `Tcl_ParseCommand` in particular, you're better off using the tclparser package as schlenk mentions. That's because the result of that function (as an out parameter) is significantly non-trivial; it needs quite a lot of converting to turn into the sort of thing that works as a Tcl value.

Comment: And yes, that's C code inside a Tcl script and it works. Critcl's pretty awesome; wish I'd written it.

Comment: This gives a ray of hope. let me try installing critcl and try a few examples. thanks a lot to all.